# How to replace a missing value with zero in a list on a condition basis in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list

I have a group by data frame with 3 columns name, category and count. there are total seven categories. each name has some categories and its count. i want to fetch a list of count name wise with all categories and its count, if a name doesn't have a any category then it should display 0 in a count.
Categories = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G']

I tried,
`for i in grouped_df['Names'].unique():`

`a=grouped_df.loc[grouped_df['Names']==i,:]`

`x=a['Count'].tolist()`

`print(x)`
and the results were,
`[7, 3, 4, 4, 2, 41, 8]`

`[3, 9, 8, 2, 22, 11]`

`[2, 1, 2, 9, 1]`

`[1, 2, 1]`

`[2, 1, 2, 9]`

`[3, 1]`

`[2]`

`[3, 2, 8, 1, 10, 9]`

In above result, 1st list have all categories count but in below list some categories count is missing because there is no data for that name in category column, So here i am expecting that if a category is missing it should get replaced by 0. Each list should have all 7 category values.
Output Should Display like,

`[7, 3, 4, 4, 2, 41, 8] [3, 9, 0, 8, 2, 22, 11] [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1] [3, 2, 0, 8, 1, 10, 9] [2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 9, 1] [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1] [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0] [2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 9]`

Comment: Please provide sample input data that demonstrates your problem. See [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
df = (grouped_df.pivot_table(index='Names', 
                             columns='category', 
                             values='Count', 
                             aggfunc='sum', 
                             fill_value=0)
                .reindex(Categories, axis=1, fill_value=0))
```

And then loop:

```
for x in df.to_numpy():
    print (x.tolist())
```

Your solution:

```
for i, g in grouped_df.set_index('category').groupby('Names'):

    x = g['Count'].reindex(Categories, axis=1, fill_value=0).tolist()
    print (x)
```